# FQL : not able to get facebook user email-id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I am using fql to fetch the list of all friends of a user and there basic info . How ever i am not able to get the email of user. below is my query :

```
$frd_fql          = "SELECT uid,
            name,
            username,
            first_name,
            middle_name,
            last_name,
            birthday_date,
            sex,
            current_location,
            email,
            relationship_status,
            languages,
            religion,
            interests,      
            hometown_location
            FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = '".$u_id."' )";
                $ret_frdobj       = $this->_facebook->api(array(
                                   'method' => 'fql.query',
                                   'query' => $frd_fql,
                ));
```

can anyonr help why i am not able to get user email ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

> can anyonr help why i am not able to get user email ?

Because getting the email address is only possible for the current user of your app, but not for their friends.

There is no such thing as a `friends_email` permission, as you can clearly see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#user_friends_perms